# vb.net Backgroundworker DoWork not ending

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am reading a `DataTable` from a soap call which takes a long time to complete.  To keep the GUI alive and update a marquee progressbar I can doing the soapcall on a background worker and waiting for it to set a global variable flag in the `Runworkercompleted` sub.
The table gets populated fine, and the dowork returns, but the runworker completed never gets called.

If I recode this to set the flag as the last thing in DOWORK then next time I call `TableGetterThread.RunWorkerAsync` it tells me that it cant run tasks concurrently
(Additional information: This `BackgroundWorker` is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.)

Any help on what I am doing wrong much appreciated.

```
    waiting = True
    TableGetterThread.RunWorkerAsync(New tableInfo(tablename, filter))
    While waiting
        Me.Refresh()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While

Private Sub TableGetterThread_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles TableGetterThread.DoWork
    Dim user As String = "username"
    Dim pass As String = "password"
    getTable_Table = Nothing
    getTable_Table = bromcomReader.getEntityData(e.Argument.tablename, e.Argument.Filter, user, pass).Tables(0)
    getTable_Table.TableName = e.Argument.tablename
    Console.WriteLine("FinishedDoWork")
End Sub

Private Sub TableGetterThread_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles TableGetterThread.RunWorkerCompleted
    Console.WriteLine("Completed")
    waiting = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `Console.WriteLine("FinishedDoWork")` from DoWork code.

Comment: Same effect, only added that later to make sure that the code was not hanging on bromcomReader.getEntityData()

Comment: Think your while loop is the problem. What happens after that? Can't you call the stuff after the wihle loop from the RunWorkerCOmpleted Sub?

Comment: This is called *deadlock*.  Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler cannot run until your UI thread goes idle.  It is not idle, it is stuck in the loop that tests the *waiting* variable.  Delete that loop.  If there is any code after it then move that code into your event handler.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice.  I have the code working now. Moved the setting of the flag to the end of the DoWork handler, and then didn't try to re-use the same BackgroundWorker object next time the function is called, but disposed of it and re-instansiated a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is in the logic itself. The Main thread and the `RunWorkerCompleted` has to run on the same thread. So while you are waiting for `Waiting` to be set to `false`, you are in main thread and so the `RunWorkerCompleted` is never called. Set `waiting = False` as the last step in `BackgroundWorker_Dowork`. And I would suggest you to use `AutoReset Event` instead of `While loop` for waiting.

You can use this code for reference.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property waiting As Boolean

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Console.WriteLine("Hey")
        waiting = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        waiting = True
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        While waiting
            Me.Refresh()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```